# Iframe - Automatically center horizontal scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How do i make an iframe automatically center the horizontal scroll position to the center when the iframe is bigger than the whole page (it takes the whole page). Without making with 100%!

Picture: [Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEWx2.jpg)

The first image shows how the site looks normally.
The second shows how it looks when i zoom out.
The third shows how i want it too look. I want it to automatically scroll to the center of the iframe horizontaly, and then hide the horizontal scroll bar, only making it possible to scroll vertically.

I have tried several different methods i found by searching, but none worked when the width was larger than the view. 
Thanks in advance! (Sorry for my bad english)

Here is some of what i tried that didnt work: (found code on stackoverflow)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body, html
{
margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="window.scrollTo((document.body.offsetWidth - document.documentElement.offsetWidth) / 2, (document.body.offsetHeight - document.documentElement.offsetHeight) / 2)
  /*
   * window.scrollTo(x,y) is an efficient cross-broser function,
   * which scrolls the document to position X, Y
   * document.body.offsetWidth contains the value of the body's width
   * document.documentElement contains the value of the document's width
   *
   * Logic: If you want to center the page, you have to substract
   * the body's width from the document's width, then divide it
   * by 2.
   */">
<iframe height="100%" frameborder="0" width="3000px" src="http://url.com">
</body>
</html>
```

And

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Test Layout</title>
<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("site"); //div#container
var elemWidth = elem.scrollWidth;
var elemVisibleWidth = elem.offsetWidth;
elem.scrollLeft = (elemWidth - elemVisibleWidth) / 2;
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body, html
{
margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; text-align: center;
}

#content
{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
 }

#site
{
    width:2600px;
}
        </style>


    </head>
<body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe id="site" name="site" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://url.com" />
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the iframe content is from a different domain, then you have no access to it at all – Same Origin Policy.

Comment: i have it in a html file too if that works

Comment: But i dont think it matters. I dont think you understood my question. I want the iframe to automatically scroll horizontally to the middle, by probably using the ScrollTo function. Thanks!

Comment: I think I understand what you _want_ – but not what your actual _problem_ with it is. / What have you done so far in terms of debugging then? Have you logged the values your script reads to console, and checked if the are plausible?